# Construction of an explicit $\mathbb{C}G$-isomorphism

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Let $G=\left<a,b:a^6=b^2=1,b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\right>.$ Let $A= \begin{pmatrix}
 e^{i\pi/3} & 0 \\
 0 & e^{-i\pi/3}  \\ 
\end{pmatrix} $$
$ , $B= \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0  \\ 
\end{pmatrix} , C  = \begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
 -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}  \\ 
\end{pmatrix} $ and $D= \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1  \\ 
\end{pmatrix}.$ Then, the representations $\rho:a^rb^s\to A^rB^s$ and $\sigma:a^rb^s\to C^rD^s$ are equivalent.

Let $V$ be the corresponding $\mathbb{C}G$-module for $\rho$ and $W$ be the corresponding $\mathbb{C}G$-module for $\sigma.$ This means $V$ is isomorphic to $W$. Could someone show me how to construct the function explicitly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just diagonalise $C$. You can check that $C$ has eigenvalues $e^{i\pi/3}$ and $e^{-i\pi/3}$ with eigenvectors $(1,i)$ and $(1,-i)$. Then if you set $P=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ i & -i\end{pmatrix}$, you have $PCP^{-1}=A$ and $PDP^{-1}=B$.

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo Both $V$ and $W$ are 2-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces. The matrix $P$ is an intertwiner of both representations (i.e. $PC=AP$ and $PD=BP$), that also happens to be an isomorphism of vector spaces (it is an invertible $2\times 2$ matrix). It is precisely an isomorphism of representations.

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo The identity $\rho(g)P=P\sigma(g)$ will hold for all $g$ because the matrices $A$, $C$ and $B,D$ correspond to the generators $a$ and $b$ respectively.

Comment: Noted, thank you for clarification. To show $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic, I need to construct an invertible linear transformation $f:V \to W.$ How would such an $f$ be defined?

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo If you let $\{v_1,v_2\}$ be a basis for $V$ and $\{w_1,w_2\}$ be a basis for $W$ then your linear map is $f(v_1)=w_1 + iw_2$ and $f(v_2)=w_1-iw_2$, extend by linearity.